# License header for CSS/JS resources

Tags: license-notice, multi-licensing

I'm creating a template for a company and fetching all vendor libs and selfmade code together to one minified style.css and script.js.

My question to you is: Is this following license header legal?

```
/*!
 * FooBar Company Template (https://foobar-company.xyz)
 * Copyright 2016 FooBoar Company
 * Unauthorized copying of this template, via any medium is strictly prohibited.
 *
 * Vendor resources
 *
 *  Font Awesome 4.6.3 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome
 *  License - http://fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 *
 *  Open Sans by Steve Matteson
 *  Licensed under Apache License 2.0
 *
 *  Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 *  Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 *  Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 *
 */
[here follows minified CSS stuff]
```

The license header for my minified JS file looks similiar.

**After reading your response my final source header looks like this**

```
/****************************************************************************
 * FooBar Company Template v1.0.0
 * Copyright 2016 | FooBar | https://foobar.xyz
 *
 * This template integrates components from the following projects
 *
 *  Font Awesome 4.7.0 by @davegandy | fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 *  Open Sans by Steve Matteson | Apache License 2.0
 *  jQuery v3.1.1 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license
 *  Bootstrap v3.3.7 | Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc. | MIT License
 *  Bootstrap Modalizer v1.0.0 | (c) 2016 Jonathan Nessier, Neoflow | MIT License
 *  Menu Icon v1.0 | (c) Neoflow | MIT License
 *  Hammer.JS v2.0.8 | Copyright (c) 2016 Jorik Tangelder | MIT License
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Well it makes it look like your proprietary license is applying to the whole thing, which is definitely less than ideal.

Comment: Should I remove the 3rd line and it is ok?

Comment: My feeling is that the third line is fine. I suppose @curiousdannii's comment has more to do with the first two lines. Rather than using the vague term `Vendor resources` I would specify `This template integrates code from the following projects:`

Answer (score 4):

> Is this following license header legal?

I cannot say if this is legal, but it sure does not look complete or correct.

Some licenses may have specific requirements that I would not properly meet unless I included the full text of the license, for instance for the [MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html):

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Some licenses may NOT be sub-licensable (as is the MIT) for instance the [SIL OFL 1.1](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web&_sc=1) and this may conflict with a proprietary notice that would essentially re/sub-license the code under another license.

> 5) The Font Software, modified or unmodified, in part or in whole,
>   must be distributed entirely under this license, and must not be
>   distributed under any other license. The requirement for fonts to
>   remain under this license does not apply to any document created
>   using the Font Software.

Additional answer elements:

> After reading your response my final source header looks like this

```
/****************************************************************************
 * FooBar Company Template v1.0.0
 * Copyright 2016 | FooBar | https://foobar.xyz
 *
 * This template integrates components from the following projects
 *
 *  Font Awesome 4.7.0 by @davegandy | fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 *  Open Sans by Steve Matteson | Apache License 2.0
 *  jQuery v3.1.1 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license
 *  Bootstrap v3.3.7 | Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc. | MIT License
 *  Bootstrap Modalizer v1.0.0 | (c) 2016 Jonathan Nessier, Neoflow | MIT License
 *  Menu Icon v1.0 | (c) Jonathan Nessier, Neoflow | MIT License
 *  Hammer.JS v2.0.8 | Copyright (c) 2016 Jorik Tangelder | MIT License
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
```

This looks fine to me with some caveats: the licenses texts would need to be included somehow if not in the code itself, at least side-by-side with your code and accessible from that code , e.g. possibly linked. The Apache-licensed packages may also have specific NOTICEs that may need to be reproduced too.